# How to properly read Axios Authorization token in NextJS for request that needs authentication?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, next.js

Well, I have a component that requires a token in order to fetch data from DB. The user usually gets the token after a successfull login:

```js
  const loginAuth = (loginData, history) => async () => {
    const res = await api.post(`/auth/login`, loginData);

    if (res.statusText === `OK`) {
      if (res.data.data) {
        history.push(`/auth/validatetwofactorauth/${res.data.data._id}`);
        return res.data;
      }

      setAuthToken(res.data.token);
      history.push('/posts');
    } else {
      console.log('error');
      // setError(res.data.error);
    }
  };
```

As you guys can see I'm calling a method with the name of `sethAuthToken`, said function looks like this:

```
export const setAuthToken = (token) => {
  if (token) {
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
      api.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${token}`;
      api.defaults.headers['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${token}`;
      localStorage.setItem('xAuthToken', token);
    }
  } else {
    delete api.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'];
    delete api.defaults.headers['Authorization'];
    localStorage.removeItem('xAuthToken');
    deleteCookie('xAuthToken', '/');
  }
};
```

After the token is received, the function above passes it to the `api.default.headers.common`; this is my **api**:

```js
import axios from 'axios';
import { API_URL } from '../config';

const api = axios.create({
  baseURL: `${API_URL}/api/v1`,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': `application/json`
  }
});

console.log('API', api.defaults);
// So far everything works great since I can actually see the token being
// retrieved in the previous console log()

api.interceptors.response.use(
  (res) => res,
  (err) => {
    return Promise.reject(err);
  }
);

export default api;
```

So far, everything works great!.

Now, the problem comes on this following request and component. This component fetches data from a request that do requires the a Bearer token(which by now should be available)

```js
import { useEffect, useState, useContext } from 'react';
import { withRouter } from 'next/router';
// ACTIONS
import { getTimelineFromServer } from '@/actions/post';
// HELPERS
import NothingFoundAlert from '@/layout/NothingFoundAlert';
import privateRoutes from '@/routing/privateRoutes';
import AuthContext from '@/routing/authContext';
// REACSTRAP
import CardColumns from 'react-bootstrap/CardColumns';
// NESTED COMPONENTS
import Single from './single';

export const getServerSideProps = async (context) => {
  const params = `?page=${context.query.page}&limit=${context.query.limit}&sort=${context.query.sort}&status=published`;
  const data = (await getTimelineFromServer(params)()) || []; // Get videos

  if (!data) {
    return { notFound: true };
  }

  return {
    props: {
      params: params,
      serverPosts: data.data,
    }
  };
};

const Timeline = ({
  params,
  serverPosts,
  router
}) => {

  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    setPosts(serverPosts);
  }, [params]);

  const { auth } = useContext(AuthContext);
  
    return posts?.length > 0 ? (
        <CardColumns>
            {posts.map((post, index) => (
                <Single
                    key={post._id}
                    post={post}
                    objects={posts}
                    auth={auth}
                />
            ))}
        </CardColumns>
    ) : (
        <NothingFoundAlert />
    )
};

export default withRouter(privateRoutes(Timeline));
```

The function that requires it, is the `getTimelineFromserver(params)() || []`; this is what it looks like:

```js
export const getTimelineFromServer = (params) => async (dispatch) => {
  console.log(api.defaults.headers.common);
  try {
    const res = await api.get(`/posts/timeline${params}`);
    console.log('Get timeline', api.defaults.headers.common);

    return res.data;
  } catch (err) {
    return { msg: err?.response?.statusText, status: err?.response?.status };
  }
};
```

Now, I'm assuming the error is in the `api.defaults.headers.common` because when I console.log-it, it only returns `{ Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*' }`.

In summary: **the token gets deleted for some reason?**

Thank you and I know this post is long but I would not be asking if I had not tried anything before; now, I'm out of ideas.

NOTE: I have a privateRoutes HOC that I use with the component above but I do not think that has anything to do with the fetching since the only thing it does is verify if X token is found, otherwise, redirect user to `/aut/login`

Comment: Your `setAuthToken` logic happens on the client-side, but the `getTimelineFromServer` happens inside `getServerSideProps` on the server. Your `axios` instance is not shared across client and server.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Trying to do the exact same thing.

Comment: Nope, I ended up using useEffect in order to read the authentication data.